# Installing clsql sqlite3 using SBCL + quicklisp

Tags: sqlite, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp, clsql

I want to use the `sqlite3` interface of [clsql](http://clsql.b9.com/manual/prerequisites.html#idp57899024). I already install `clsql` using quicklisp. But when I try to run:

```
(clsql:with-database (db '("database.db") 
                          :database-type :sqlite3)
  nil)
```

I get

```
OPERATION-ERROR while invoking #<COMPILE-OP > on
#<CLSQL-UFFI-SOURCE-FILE "clsql-uffi" "uffi" "clsql_uffi">
   [Condition of type ASDF/BACKWARD-INTERFACE:OPERATION-ERROR]
```

It is the same if I just try to quicklisp `clsql-uffi`.

`cl-sql`,`cl-sql-uffi`,`cl-sql-sqlite3` and `libsqlite3-dev` are installed. I am using Ubuntu,Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit: Separated the problem topics more clearly.*

Installing CLSQL is not always straightforward.

- CLSQL builds foreign libraries for its database interfaces, so make sure you have `build-essentials` installed as well. To check that the foreign libraries compile successfully (and if not, to check the error message), I recommend running `make` on a terminal in the respective directories.
- [There's a bug in clsql makefiles that affect certain systems, most notably AWS instances](http://lists.b9.com/pipermail/clsql/2014-April/002188.html) - check if that applies on your system. Fix the makefiles in the quicklisp's clsql directories as necessary.
- On earlier Ubuntu versions, I successfully used the distribution's of `cl-sql` package. On 14.04+, however, they do not usually work too well - so installing `clsql` from quicklisp is probably a better idea.

Comment: I purged `cl-sql` from my system, then restarted slime and loaded `clsql`and `clsql-uffi`. Worked like a charm